# How to parameterize a surface?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surfaces

How to parameterize the surface defined by $xy^2 +xz^2-yz=0$?I put y=u,z=v so $x=\frac{uv}{u^2+v^2}$,if it is alright,what kind of surface is this?

Answer (score 3):

The parametrization is OK.

The surface is in the picture below

[image]